# Disable TAB access to control in WinForms

Tags: winforms, controls

Can I somehow disable access by TAB on come controls on form in WinForms
(controls like textboxes must be enabled for access and writing but when user hits TAB it will access only buttons)

Comment: As Robert says, set the TabStop property to false for the controls, you don't want the user to reach when they TAB their way through.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the TabStop property of the control to false.

Answer (score 1):

You can set TabStop=false for individual controls.

Answer (score 0):

Find the `Tab Stop` property on the the `Other` tab of the property sheet and set it to `No` for each TextBox you want to prevent the users from tabbing to.